# Putting matplotlib hexbin into an Aitoff projection

Tags: python, matplotlib, map-projections, astropy, hexagonal-tiles

I have the nice hexbin plot below, but I'm wondering if there is any way to get hexbin into an Aitoff projection? The salient code is:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import ascii

filename = 'WISE_W4SNRge3_and_W4MPRO_lt_6.0_RADecl_nohdr.dat'
datafile= path+filename
data = ascii.read(datafile)  
points = np.array([data['ra'], data['dec']])

color_map = plt.cm.Spectral_r 
points = np.array([data['ra'], data['dec']]) 
xbnds = np.array([ 0.0,360.0]) 
ybnds = np.array([-90.0,90.0]) 
extent = [xbnds[0],xbnds[1],ybnds[0],ybnds[1]] 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4)) 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) 
x, y = points 
gsize = 45 
image = plt.hexbin(x,y,cmap=color_map, 
    gridsize=gsize,extent=extent,mincnt=1,bins='log') 

counts = image.get_array() 
ncnts = np.count_nonzero(np.power(10,counts)) 
verts = image.get_offsets() 

ax.set_xlim(xbnds) 
ax.set_ylim(ybnds) 
plt.xlabel('R.A.')  
plt.ylabel(r'Decl.') 
plt.grid(True) 
cb = plt.colorbar(image, spacing='uniform', extend='max') 
plt.show()
```

and I've tried:

```
plt.subplot(111, projection="aitoff")
```

before doing the `plt.hexbin` command, but which only gives a nice, but blank, Aitoff grid.

[image]

Comment: In principle there is no problem of plotting a `hexbin` plot in any projection. Without a [mcve], noone can know where your problem lies.

Comment: Is the (hopefully) minimal, complete code. The RA/Decl or x,y data points can be, as is given above, just a numpy array.

Comment: There are basically no examples I can find of hexbin being used for an Aitoff projection, so I don't think it's as easy as just using "plotting a hexbin plot in any projection..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the Aitoff projection uses radians, from -π to +π. Not degrees from 0 to 360. I use the `Angle.wrap_at` function to achieve this, as per [this Astropy example](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/skycoord.html#example-1-plotting-random-data-in-aitoff-projection) (which essentially tells you how to create a proper Aitoff projection plot).

In addition, you can't change the axis limits (that'll lead to an error), and shouldn't use `extent` (as ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer also states).

You can change your code as follows to get what you want:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import ascii
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
from astropy import units

filename = 'WISE_W4SNRge3_and_W4MPRO_lt_6.0_RADecl_nohdr.dat'
data = ascii.read(filename)
coords = SkyCoord(ra=data['ra'], dec=data['dec'], unit='degree')
ra = coords.ra.wrap_at(180 * units.deg).radian
dec = coords.dec.radian

color_map = plt.cm.Spectral_r
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
fig.add_subplot(111, projection='aitoff')
image = plt.hexbin(ra, dec, cmap=color_map,
                   gridsize=45, mincnt=1, bins='log')

plt.xlabel('R.A.')
plt.ylabel('Decl.')
plt.grid(True)
plt.colorbar(image, spacing='uniform', extend='max')
plt.show()
```

Which gives
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem lies in the use of the `extent` which is set to something other than the range of the spherical coordinate system.

The following works fine:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ra = np.linspace(-np.pi/2.,np.pi/2.,1000)
dec = np.sin(ra)*np.pi/2./2.
points = np.array([ra, dec]) 

plt.subplot(111, projection="aitoff")

color_map = plt.cm.Spectral_r 
x, y = points 
gsize = 45 
image = plt.hexbin(x,y,cmap=color_map, 
                   gridsize=45,mincnt=1,bins='log') 

plt.xlabel('R.A.')  
plt.ylabel(r'Decl.') 
plt.grid(True) 
cb = plt.colorbar(image, spacing='uniform', extend='max') 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm.... So I can get your code e.g. working and reproducing the plot above. What I cant do is take my astropy.table and get anything sensible.

Comment: I've modified the code above. The data are here:: 
  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4qsv753bhksn6ur/AAB4kthAcvmx_kQRa0zhkhQ0a?dl=0

Comment: I don't have astropy available.

Comment: > pip3 install astropy